# Mathematical task with point numbers

Tags: c, math, int

I just started to study about C Programing.

I want to write a program to solve this mathematical task (1/2*r<sup>2</sup>*3.14)

This is the code that I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
int r=5;
float sum;
sum = 1/2*r^2*3.14;
printf("%f", sum);
getch();
}
```

but there is an error and I don`t know what the mistake is.
First I thought that there is something wrong about the number 3.14, but when I changed it to 3 the program ran but the answer was 6.0000 but it should be 37.5

Comment: `1/2` is always 0 since you're doing `int` calculations.

Comment: `main()` should be `int main()` or `int main(void)` and add a `return 0;` at the end. Didn't your compiler (at least) give out a warning for this? Even the ancient and legendary TurboC emits a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C there is no operator for power calculation. `^` is used as XOR operator. You need to use library function `pow` for power calculations.

```
sum = 1.0 / 2 * pow(r,2) * 3.14;
```

Note that I changed `1/2` to `1.0/2` because `1/2` will always give `0` and the result you will get is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

**^** is bitwise XOR operator. You have to use pow() for your purpose

```
sum = 1.0/2.0*pow(r,2)*3.14;
```

Your code will give you 6.000. Because **^** is using as **xor** operator

```
1/2*r^2*3 = (0)d ^ (6)d =  (000)b ^ (110)b = (110)b = (6)d
```

But, 3.14 instead of 3 will give you error

```
1/2*r^2*3.14
```

Because, **Xor** operator don't take double as operand

Comment: It's enough to `.0` only one side.

Comment: *There is no ^ operator*: are you serious?

Comment: `^` is not power operator, but it is one of the most important operators in programming, xor.

Answer (score 0):

The `^` operator is not for power raising you can write it explicitly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
    int r=5;
    float sum;
    /* 1/2 * r^2 * pi <- this is the expression */
    sum = 1.57 * r * r;
    printf("%f", sum);
    getch();
}
```

the expression has no meaning in the program except for someone reading it, so you can add a comment and write the values directly.

And in case you are going to raise to a higher power just use the `pow()` function.

Also, if you skip the `.0` the compiler assumes the values as integers, and `1/2` is `0.5` truncated it yeilds `0`, `1./2` would also work, but not `1/2`.

Comment: When 0.5 is rounded,the result will be 1 not 0. The correct word for it would be "truncated",i.e, the decimal part is ignored.